# Selecting multiple ID's from a table gives error ORA-02070

Tags: sql, database, oracle

When I try to select multiple ID's from a table, I am getting error ORA-02070.

Here is the query that I am using:

```
select *
from   hrs_employee_store 
where  employee_id in (13511677, 576000);
```

Here is the error which I am getting:

> ORA-02070: database ODS_XSTORE does not support TO_NUMBER in this context

Also, when I use this query,

```
select * from hrs_employee_store 
where  employee_id in ('13511677', '576000');
```

I am just getting the row for `13511677`.

Is there a way to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: looks like they are not integers- put single quotes around the numbers

Comment: If you are getting just one result for two given ID, then you do not have the exact same entry in the DB, e.g. it's not '576000', but maybe ' 57600' or '57600 ' (with a white space in it, or whatever other character). You could try verifying it by using a more relaxed search term, e.g. `SELECT * FROM hrs_employee_store WHERE employee_id LIKE '%576000%'`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `EMPLOYEE_ID` is not a number.  Try:

```
select *
from hrs_employee_store 
where EMPLOYEE_ID in ('13511677', '576000');
```

This returns matching employees, meaning there is no match for the second.

If you want `NULL` values for all the extra columns, you can use `left join`:

```
select *
from (select '13511677' as employee_id from dual union all
      select '576000'
     ) eid left join
     hrs_employee_store es
     using (employee_id);
```

Comment: select *
from hrs_employee_store 
where EMPLOYEE_ID in ('13511677', '576000')
;    When I try this, I am getting only 1 employee id's row. i.e, 13511677. But I need to select both the ID's

Comment: Your original query had the same id listed twice

Comment: @DanielMarcus Edited it. Thanks

Comment: So are you still having an issue when you put quotes around both numbers?

Comment: @DanielMarcus Yes, I am.

Comment: Double check and make sure that ID actually exists in the table